# WP Custom Post Type Backend View

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a Custom Post Type with the Custom Post Type UI plugin.

I have added a number of custom fields which are connected to this custom post type.

I want to create a Backend View for the custom post type where the user can see the post without the ability to Edit the post.

I need help on the following issues:

- Overriding the 'View' button shown for every entry to point to the 'Backend View' page
- Creating the 'Backend View'

Edited due to a suggestion:

The Custom Post type that I have created isn't shown through the website it is meant as Booking, each Booking input is added as a post entry, which currently can only be viewed in Edit mode. Which creates a problem as I want the edit mode to be available to 'Super' Admins only.

Apart from the above the View button which is automatically shown for each entry directs you to the homepage, I want this to be either overriden and directed to a View page or completely removed so to not confuse the users.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Edited, but following your comment this forum might not be the right forum for my question can you suggest a forum for this type of question?

Comment: Please note that this isn't a forum, it's a Q&A website. Questions requesting links to off-site resources such as tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow.